# Get the sum of 3rd property if first two properties matches

Tags: arrays, arraylist, properties

I have three properties in an array. I want the the sum of the 3rd property when the first 2 properties have the same value. My goal is to have an array in which the first two properties are unique.

For the following example

```
var arrayPeople = [
    {
        name: 'joe',
        category: 'leave',
        count: 2,
    },
    {
        name: 'bob',
        category: 'travel',
        count: 1,
    },
    {
        name: 'joe',
        category: 'leave',
        count: 1,
    },
    {
        name: 'bob',
        category: 'travel',
        count: 3,
    };   
];
```

I would expect

```
arrayPeople = [
    {
        name: 'joe',
        category: 'leave',
        count: 3,
    },
    {
        name: 'bob',
        category: 'travel',
        count: 4,
    };
];
```

There is only one occurrence of `name: 'joe', category: 'leave'` and its `count: 3` is the sum of the two counts in the first array.

Comment: In which language? Plus your question is not very clear.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add which language you are using? Also, what have you tried already and where are you stuck?

Comment: in jquery/ javascript. anyway i have got the solution. Thank you.

Comment: here is the solution:  
var helper = {};
 result = arr.reduce(function(r, o) {
    var key = o.Name + '-' + o.Category;
  
  if(!helper[key]) {
    helper[key] = Object.assign({}, o); // create a copy of o
    r.push(helper[key]);
  } else {
    helper[key].Count += o.Count;
    //helper[key].instances += o.instances;
  }

  return r;
}, []);